# Woher kommt die Bezeichnung "Rutschauto"?

Tags: etymology

Wie ich vor nicht allzu langer Zeit gelernt habe, lautet die Sammelbezeichnung für Fahrzeuge, auf denen (für gewöhnlich Klein-)Kinder sitzen und die durch Abstoßen mit den Füßen am Boden vorwärtsgetrieben werden (Bobby-Cars sind eines von vielen Beispielen), **Rutschauto** bzw. **Rutschfahrzeug**.

**Woher kommt dieser Begriff?**

Mir ist nicht klar, was genau an solchen Fahrzeugen irgendwo "rutscht".

- Das Fahrzeug selber rutscht nicht aüber den Boden, denn es hat ja Räder, die sich i.A. flüssig drehen.
- Das Kind rutscht auch nicht über den Boden, denn der einzige Kontakt mit dem Boden findet ja beim Abstoßen statt, währenddessen die Füße nach Möglichkeit den Boden an einer einzigen Stelle kraftschlüssig berühren, ohne abzurutschen. (Allenfalls beim Bremsen während hoher Geschwindkgeit könnte man von einem "Rutschen" sprechen.)

Comment: Kann es sein, dass die Kinder auf dem Auto herumrutschen, um ihre Füße besser nach vorne oder hinten zu bekommen?

Comment: @infinitezero: Das wäre eventuell eine Erklärung, immerhin ist diese Rutschbewegung auf dem Sitz eher noch stärker ausgeprägt als bei Tretfahrzeugen.

Comment: Als Mama kann ich aus Erfahrung sagen: Der gesamte Unterschenkel, das Knie und natürlich Ober- und Unterseite der Füße rutscht im Extremfall über den Boden. Vor den Rutschautos gab es Schaukelpferde, die besonderen Spaß machen, wenn man den Dreh raus hat und sie beim Schaukeln vorwärts(oder rückwärts) rutschen lässt. Da die Bewegung der Kinder auf dem Pferd und dem AUto ähnlich ist, erinnert es wohl viele Erwachsene an dieses Rutschen. (Geht übrigens auch mit allen räderlosen Sitzgelegenheiten, wie Stühlen, Bänken, GUmmitieren...)

Answer (score 3):

Die zweite Annahme, dass der Bodenkontakt nur zum Abstoßen stattfindet, entspricht nicht den Tatsachen. Wegen der niedrigen Bauhöhe schleifen die Füße permanent über den Boden (siehe etwa [hier](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.ipGU5xCU39Mo__W2K2FpcgHaE6%26pid%3DApi&f=1)). Aufgrund des massiven Verschleißes von Schuhsohlen (besonders die Schuhspitze ist massiv beansprucht) habe ich schon gehört, dass Eltern die Nutzung solcher Vehikel nur barfuß erlauben. Von daher beschreibt *rutschen* den Vorgang deutlich besser als *rollen* oder gar *fahren*.

Comment: Ob sich die Eltern das mit dem barfuß aufgrund des massiven Verschleißes von Füßen (besonders die Zehen sind massiv beansprucht) nicht schnell wieder anders überlegen, wage ich zu bezweifeln ;) Die Beobachtung stimmt natürlich schon - aber ich bin noch nicht überzeugt, dass das der namensgebende Vorgang sein kann. Das ist ja eher ein unerwünschter Nebeneffekt (der zudem gar nicht am Fahrzeug auftritt, sondern an seinem Insassen), während das Fahrzeug selber ja durchaus rollt bzw. fährt.

Answer (score 3):

Für den Begriff muss man sich ansehen, für wen die Rutschautos eigentlich so <s>[gebaut werden](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lo4mu0pAeBQ)</s> gemacht sind. Für Kleinkinder ab ca. 12 Monaten. Wenn man sich anschaut wie [diese sich damit fortbewegen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TX5bNy2l2-Y) wird schnell klar, dass das mit "fahren" oder "rollen" wenig zu tun hat. (Dass größere Kinder und vor allem "ganz große Kinder" damit [Downhill] fahren ist natürlich richtig.)

Um mal den [Bobby-Car-Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobby-Car) zu zitieren

> Das Bobby-Car wurde entwickelt, um kleinen Kindern das Laufenlernen zu erleichtern. [...] Durch Paddelbewegungen mit den Beinen kann es das Auto fortbewegen.

Die Bewegungen erinnern zumindest an rutschen, besonders wenn man es mit den als [Popo-Rutscher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3QZhIOmx_4) bekannten Babys vergleicht.

Zuletzt noch ein Zitat aus "Einheit: Zeitung für Mitglieder der IG Bergbau und Energie - Seite 71" von 1980.

> Frühestens in diesem Alter lernt es, mit dem ersten Fahrzeug sinnvoll umzugehen, und rutscht damit vergnügt im Haus oder auf dem Spielplatz herum. Viele Hersteller haben ihren Fahrzeugen daher die Bezeichnung Rutsch-Auto gegeben.

Comment: "wird schnell klar, dass das mit "fahren" oder "rollen" wenig zu tun hat." - in dem verlinkten Video sieht man doch ganz deutlich, dass das Bobbycar auf seinen vier Rädern rollt und eben nicht rutscht.

Comment: Der Aussage, dass die schubweise Fortbewegung an das Rutschen kleiner Kinder über den Boden erinnert, stimme ich allerdings zu.

Comment: Das abschließende Zitat wiederum kann ich nicht nachvollziehen - unter "rutscht damit vergnügt im Haus oder auf dem Spielplatz herum" kann ich mir eigentlich nur vorstellen, dass das Fahrzeug auf der Seite liegt, sodass die Räder keinen Kontakt zum Boden haben, und auf diese Weise über den Boden gezogen wird. Gerade bei so einem Umgang mit dem Spielzeug finde ich es aber zweifelhaft, von einem "sinnvollen Umgang" zu sprechen. Oder ist unter "rutschen" irgendwie noch eine andere Bedeutung zu verstehen als die einer Schleifbewegung über eine Oberfläche ohne sich drehende Rollen dazwischen?